# Mod-rewrite url from /example.php?id=1 to /example/title-of-page

Tags: php, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a website that generates urls like:

www.site.com/example.php?id=1

I would like that url to be displayed like:

www.site.com/example/the-title-of-the-page-whatever-it-may-be

Can I do this in .htaccess or do I need to edit the php or what?

Be gentle, and treat me like an idiot please - I'm brand new to all this :)

Comment: you can use apache mod_rewrite with PHP slug. google it and you get loads of solution.

Comment: here is a simple tutorial that can help you out. http://papermashup.com/create-a-url-from-a-string-of-text-with-php/

Answer (score 1):

If your using a apache server you can use [mod rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use this for your htaccess :

> RewriteEngine On
>   RewriteRule ^([^/]*).html$ /example.php?id=$1 [L]

**Your Old URL >** example.com/example.php?id=1

**Will be change to >** example.com/1.html

Using id :

> RewriteEngine On
>   RewriteRule ^id/([^/]*).html$ /example.php?id=$1 [L]

**Your Old URL >** example.com/example.php?id=1

**Will be change to >** example.com/id/1.html

Hope Help you ;)

Answer (score 0):

You indeed need an .htaccess file for this and of course some PHP code to see what page needs to be loaded. The .htaccess could look something like this:

```
# Start rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On

# Catch non existing files and/or folders (treat as optimized urls)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|pl|txt)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Catch blocked folders (treat as optimized urls)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```